# How to get a list of non-directory files in a directory in Aix or Unix?

Tags: ksh, aix

I want to get a list of non-directory files in a directory. The `find` command is working, but the `maxdepth 1` option is not working, maybe because it is not supported on Aix.

This command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

returns:

```
find: bad option -maxdepth
```

I used this command:

```
ls -l | grep ^- | awk '{print $9}'
```

but this does not work if the file name contains a space. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off your last attempt, this seems to work okay:

```bsh
ls -l | grep ^- | awk '{for(i=1;i<9;i++) $i="";print}' | sed 's/^        //'
```

There might be a better way (I kind of hope there is!) but this collapses the first eight fields, leaving eight spaces and then the rest of the line (so spaces in file names are okay), and then removes those leading eight spaces.

I prefer this bash version that cuts to the chase:

```bsh
for f in *; do if [ -f "$f" ]; then echo "$f"; fi; done
```

I'm sure you can tweak that for ksh (which I'm not familiar with).

I'm still hoping someone else will know of something more straightforward.

Comment: Both these solutions are working in ksh but if I give more than one consecutive spaces in file name ,it does not work;for example if file name is 'abc(4 spaces)d.txt' then it is displaying result as 'abc d.txt'

Comment: If I put ""  on $f in echo $f the code works :

for f in *; do if [ -f "$f" ]; then echo "$f"; fi; done              Thanks Darshan, I am ok with this for loop version but for knowledge sake if I have to do same thing with:  ls -l | grep ^- | awk '{for(i=1;i<9;i++) $i="";print}' | sed 's/^        //'    is that possible?

Comment: @user1484782 1) Yes, thanks for pointing that out -- there should definitely be quotes around that. I've updated my answer. 2) There's probably a way to preserve the spaces in awk, but I can't think of it offhand. The shell version is shorter and more directly represents what you're trying to do, so I'd just stick with that. 3) Welcome to Stack Overflow! 4) Don't forget to select my answer as your selected answer. You can always change that if someone comes along with a better answer later.

Comment: If you had used the Korn shell [[ test (rather than Bourne shell [) then you would not have needed the quotes - that's one of the differences between [[ and [  (but quotes are still needed around a literal containing whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me for files that contain more than one space in the name.  Reduces it to a single pipe.
I'd personally like to find something more elegant.

```
ls -l | awk '/^-/ {for(i=9;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s ", $i}print "";}'
```